# Rails / PostGIS / RGeo Error: NoMethodError: undefined method `factory' for RGeo::GeoJSON::Feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, rgeo

I am using Ruby on Rails and PostGIS to store GeoJSON map data in a model called, "Map". When I save an object loaded successfully with a simple GeoJSON feature I get the error, "NoMethodError: undefined method `factory' for #".

See below for examples, setup, what I've tried, and links to resources.

## Example 1 (using Rails console)

```
irb(main):007:0> feature = '{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {  "name": "Coors Field",  "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",  "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!" }, "geometry": {  "type": "Point",  "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621] }}'
=> "{ \"type\": \"Feature\", \"properties\": {  \"name\": \"Coors Field\",  \"amenity\": \"Baseball Stadium\",  \"popupContent\": \"This is where the Rockies play!\" }, \"geometry\": {  \"type\": \"Point\",  \"coordinates\": [-104.99404, 39.75621] }}"

irb(main):008:0> geom_feature = RGeo::GeoJSON.decode(feature)
=> #<RGeo::GeoJSON::Feature:0x304e48c id=nil geom="POINT (-104.99404 39.75621)">

irb(main):009:0> Map.create(name: 'demo', geometry: geom_feature)
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `factory' for #<RGeo::GeoJSON::Feature:0x000000000609c918>
  from (irb):9
```

## Setup

- Rails 5.1.4
- PostGIS 9.6
- Docker DB src: kartoza/postgis:9.6-2.4
- Docker web src: ruby 2.3.5

## Files

config/initializers/rgeo.rb

```
RGeo::ActiveRecord::SpatialFactoryStore.instance.tap do |config| 
  config.default = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326) 
end
```

Gemfile

```
# Mapping
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'
gem 'rgeo'
gem 'rgeo-geojson'
# need this? found on random post - willing to try anything
gem 'rgeo-activerecord'
```

db/migrate/20182039293939_create_maps.rb

```
create_table :maps do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.st_polygon :polygon
  t.geometry :geometry
  t.multi_polygon :multi_polygon
  t.references :mappable, polymorphic: true, index: true

  t.timestamps
end
```

## Sources

Among others I've gone through the following sources without any luck:

[Daniel Azuma's original post about setup from 2011](http://daniel-azuma.com/articles/georails/part-2)

[StackOverflow post that talks about why part of that is obsolete 2015-06-26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834862/nomethoderror-using-activerecord-postgis-adapter)

- Note the comment below the accepted answer that clarifies how to set a default spherical factory for everything - which is fine for me and what I did above.

[Github issue response that doesn't seem relevant given that this is already a single feature](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo-geojson/issues/34)

[More recent and active Github activerecord-postgis-adaptor response that hit on all points above](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/issues/185)

[Suggests that despite not using Geos the install needs to be wrestled with 2015](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/issues/190)

- I'm still messing with this option despite it not seeming relevant
- Tried and had no effect (see below)

## Attempts

I also tried installing Geos but this made no difference.

In container:

```
apt install libgeos-dev
gem uninstall rgeo && gem install rgeo
```

In Rails Console: (after restart)

```
irb(main):001:0> RGeo::Geos.supported?
=> true
```

Attempt and outcome same as above (Example 1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the geometry of the feature (call Feature#geometry):

```
json = '{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "Coors Field",  "amenity": "Baseball Stadium", "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point",  "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621] }}'

feature = RGeo::GeoJSON.decode(json)

Map.create(name: 'demo', geometry: feature.geometry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, tee.

I build on your example to show what worked for me. The only difference lies on the last line, where rgeo needs you to inform the feature's index.

```
json = '{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "Coors Field",  "amenity": "Baseball Stadium", "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point",  "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621] }}'

feature = RGeo::GeoJSON.decode(json)

Map.create(name: 'demo', geometry: feature[0].geometry)
```